# Accessing Dynamics CRM 2011 data through a website using only HTML5, JS, and CSS

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Looking to create a completely external portal using only HTML5, JS, and CSS to show CRM 2011 data.  It does not look like I can use REST or SOAP because they cannot authenticate externally.  Does anyone know how I would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, your [OrganizationData.svc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) service would need to be externally accessible, and it would need to function without authentication (or, your authentication would need to happen within your javascript - where the end user would be able to read your source code). Either way is not a wise idea, since all of your data would be visible to the world!

If you are only dealing with internal authenticated users, read up on the oDATA endpoint.

If you want to deal with external and/or unauthenticated users, you'll need to find another way to do this that does all of the data filtering & authorization control you need.

Comment: I am actually not to worried as this is not to actually be implemented, i just want to know how it works.  Do you have any examples or links on how to have the authentication happen in the JS?  Cant seem to find it.

Comment: Please see the above URL for OrganizationData.svc - at the bottom are links to a few example code libraries, including [a jQuery example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx) and a [pure JavaScript example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think we normally achieve this using a intermediary integration service.  You could have a service which has access to the Org service through conventional CRM authentication, and which provides a number of methods which can be called anonymously (or by custom security) by client code.

For example, a web page calls the 'int' service's 'getContact' method, passing an email address of the user.  The 'int' service validates the user's email address and then retrieves the required data from CRM's org service, using credentials stored in a config file (a CRM user with sufficient permissions to serve the 'int' service's methods).  The 'int' service then parses the data and returns it to the client code - which has no knowledge of CRM's existence - perhaps as JSON for usability.